# Weird Errors on Opencart site after trying to install SSL

Tags: php, ssl, opencart

I was trying to install an SSL certificate for my site that's based on Opencart platform. Everything was fine but now when I go the site I'm getting this error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: token in /home/sama/public_html/promstardresses.com/admin/controller/error/not_found.php on line 15Notice: Undefined index: token in /home/sama/public_html/promstardresses.com/admin/controller/error/not_found.php on line 21
```

Fatal error: Call to a member function isLogged() on a non-object in /home/sama/public_html/promstardresses.com/admin/controller/common/header.php on line 74r

I reverted my config files back to the default settings, the only other thing I changed was the .htaccess file and that is back to default now. I never changed the files that are showing the errors. Any tips would be appreciated, thx.

Comment: Try changing back the url to non-ssl and seeing if that works ok. I'm guessing it's not the SSL at fault here

Comment: Hi Jay, yeah I gave that try and that didn't work either. Here's what I find in my error log:

Comment: [11-Jan-2012 20:22:44] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function isLogged() on a non-object in /home/sama/public_html/promstardresses.com/admin/controller/common/header.php on line 74

Comment: Strange. Which version of OpenCart are you currently using? and are you using vQmod?

Comment: im using 1.4.9.3 and no vQmod

Comment: @SamAbouna Can you clean up the comment section with Jay?  Right now, you're using Stack Overflow as a debugging service, and that's really not what it's for.  Your question borders *very* much on too localized.

Answer (score 0):

The issue appears to be with the upload. From visiting the domain you have there (promstardresses.com) it is trying to go to the error page in the admin even when visiting the main site. Are you sure you uploaded the files into the correct folder and with the right structure? Also, make sure the config files are set up correctly with the paths to folders

Comment: I've gone everything and it looks good, I've downloaded Opencart locally and compared the file structure, compared the config files both in the site root and admin folder and also the .htaccess file and still no luck. This is quite puzzling ......

Comment: This is the line of code in question:if (!$this->user->isLogged() || !isset($this->request->get['token']) || !isset($this->session->data['token']) || ($this->request->get['token'] != $this->session->data['token'])) {
   $this->data['logged'] = '';

Comment: and below that:           $this->data['home'] = HTTPS_SERVER . 'index.php?route=common/login';
  } else {

Comment: I have a feeling it's trying to read the wrong HTTP settings but the error messages don't verify my conclusion.

Comment: It really seems like you've got the folders incorrectly set up. OpenCart creates the `user` object in the admin/index.php file, but your main domain shouldn't be using the admin, which is where the issue arises. You've definitely got folders mixed up, or the paths to them at least. I would recommend re-uploading

Comment: ok i deleted my admin folder downloaded my version of Opencart and re-uploaded the admin folder. It seems I had an admin folder within the admin folder so I had two different admin folders. I prolly when trying to configure files for the SSL accidentaly somehow put that folder in there. I'm giving it a go and see if that will fix the problem. I think it that would the type of error message I'm getting.

Comment: I've tried everything I know still no luck. I can still log into my admin as is. When I re-upload a new admin folder I get errors on the admin side of the site so I revereted back to my previous admin folder. I've been working on this since last night and still I got no idea how to fix it.

Comment: if (!$this->user->isLogged() || !isset($this->request->get['token']) || !isset($this->session->data['token']) || ($this->request->get['token'] != $this->session->data['token'])) {
   $this->data['logged'] = '';

Comment: its that line that's giving problems from admin/controller/common location.

Comment: It's still going to be the structure. If you remove everything and upload a fresh install of OC (same version) I guarantee these errors will stop

Comment: Won't I lose all my data in the process? I have over 5000 products on my store.

Comment: Back up the database and files beforehand

Comment: Ok when I import my database to the clean install should I drop the current database that opencart installs or just empty it? or it doesn't matter?

Comment: well I tried this on a test domain I have. I did a clean install of Opencart ver 1.4.9.3 and tried to import my database and I get this SQL error: SQL query:

-- -- Dumping data for table `order_product` -- INSERT INTO `order_product` (`order_product_id`, `order_id`, `product_id`, `name`, 
MySQL said: 

#1054 - Unknown column 'subtract' in 'field list'

Comment: well i dropped the database and reuploaded and now its a bit better but when clicking on a product from the home page it gives a 404 error.

Comment: You need to add the .htaccess file correctly for the SEO Urls to work (rename from .htaccess.txt to .htaccess

Comment: Contact your host. They will be able to help you with that, as that _is_ what you need to do. If you have, then something is the matter with the server configuration

Comment: it's weird cause I installed everything on a new site, home page is fine. If i click on any link in takes me to my previous site that had the issue and it gives me the same error message from previous site.    www.starzdresses.com

Comment: I asked my hosting company for help and they just said that the SSL was installed and they have no reason why my site is not working now.

Comment: There's nothing more that can be said really. The issue is fixed as far as your original question, and the urls not working is definitely a htaccess issue